# Lexik JWT Token not found

Tags: php, jwt, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I've seen similar questions but still can't get this to work.

I'm new with Symfony and I'm using Lexik JWT bundle with symfony3 for API authentication, and a login form for web authentication.

I get the token ok but when I try to use it I get 401 - Bad authentication. 
I've read it can be an apache problem so I'm trying with PHP's built-in web server, but still no luck.

Here's my security.yml file:

```
security:

encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false
        provider: our_db_provider

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        provider: our_db_provider
        lexik_jwt:
          authorization_header: # check token in Authorization Header
            enabled: true
            prefix:  Bearer
          throw_exceptions:        true     # When an authentication failure occurs, return a 401 response immediately
          create_entry_point:      true      # When no authentication details are provided, create a default entry point that returns a 401 response


    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
          login_path: /login
          check_path: /login_check
        provider: our_db_provider

access_control:
  - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
  - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] }
```

If I set the create_entry_point to false in my api firewall, I get a 500 error: A Token was not found in the TokenStorage.

Maybe I'm passing the token the wrong way? I've tried several ways as I'm not sure which one is correct. Here are my headers:

```
POST /api/notifications HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Authorization: bearer {"token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTUwMDk1ODAsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYXNvcmlhIiwiaWF0IjoiMTQ1NDkyMzE4MCJ9.rwgAkLBesTYOZn3B96Jlsf9_3Qy-rjrRt2l5UxdXD8ZadJ2YbK-9m7qNqUd9-bhaA_MFL1lssPZ-0AzmQCZx8bL8XD_l2_df0wfVm6Le6pEJEJk0arbyxlEOZ-9LrRdOa6EjnzDcZT6Wn76QNOsCSjME7rjk0w0lLs4eXAaXGAYL6lqU4YoiM1xnifzHgGtJKc7RBBivY8yHjfs51S6GwEKzPGrYMUTZWmjhxFPlKZCqEJlaJ6NT82A3PuoISCMUvt7AuxhHdgeuS-TMjdTY-WhqaL7f7Z2FP0_FstKVORHDzC1vf7VlylF76SnF0Sh2tMTuvf70zYnD_gF0k7b9zoOp54e0mJt0XaLTyCtomPSeDhfJV1wJY6EZsrvdUrrHXXtXhA6K70FIM_nQJPVo4Raht-hQWmOnWb3Ib0SvvytQHP96klXVgKHyIaicEjvWhmonzgSRndme4HGXlPWmbKH6tVJpvWatOeaWD4jjS-ZLD_5oBr_o3vNPw81oZj0huI6OgzYvXDpLPw3P7Ma4LmBdQOLwpUEPG3LnuKIdU27umFTrN3T-Cfrb6kITU1BTaTL-AIOM-F6FDlcgJfYxOs6GEFOlFtjJ5KSAEiY8DWiubbrS-VH9uaMlc9YapTlNVsUI7whzO7QmXzC-V8idrNoWBWVftyMDlA9YR_D7N9E"}
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Or

```
    POST /api/notifications HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Authorization: bearer {"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTUwMDk1ODAsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYXNvcmlhIiwiaWF0IjoiMTQ1NDkyMzE4MCJ9.rwgAkLBesTYOZn3B96Jlsf9_3Qy-rjrRt2l5UxdXD8ZadJ2YbK-9m7qNqUd9-bhaA_MFL1lssPZ-0AzmQCZx8bL8XD_l2_df0wfVm6Le6pEJEJk0arbyxlEOZ-9LrRdOa6EjnzDcZT6Wn76QNOsCSjME7rjk0w0lLs4eXAaXGAYL6lqU4YoiM1xnifzHgGtJKc7RBBivY8yHjfs51S6GwEKzPGrYMUTZWmjhxFPlKZCqEJlaJ6NT82A3PuoISCMUvt7AuxhHdgeuS-TMjdTY-WhqaL7f7Z2FP0_FstKVORHDzC1vf7VlylF76SnF0Sh2tMTuvf70zYnD_gF0k7b9zoOp54e0mJt0XaLTyCtomPSeDhfJV1wJY6EZsrvdUrrHXXtXhA6K70FIM_nQJPVo4Raht-hQWmOnWb3Ib0SvvytQHP96klXVgKHyIaicEjvWhmonzgSRndme4HGXlPWmbKH6tVJpvWatOeaWD4jjS-ZLD_5oBr_o3vNPw81oZj0huI6OgzYvXDpLPw3P7Ma4LmBdQOLwpUEPG3LnuKIdU27umFTrN3T-Cfrb6kITU1BTaTL-AIOM-F6FDlcgJfYxOs6GEFOlFtjJ5KSAEiY8DWiubbrS-VH9uaMlc9YapTlNVsUI7whzO7QmXzC-V8idrNoWBWVftyMDlA9YR_D7N9E"}
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authorization header should be

`Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9....9YR_D7N9E`

Comment: Yeah, that was it!
The problem seemed to be in the lowercase "bearer", since now it works with and without the braces. I would have sworn I tried with the uppercase B at first, but I suppose something was wrong with my configuration back then.
Thank you so much! ^^

Comment: Yes and if you read carefully the configuration of the firewall, you will see that you can change it: change `prefix:  Bearer` into `prefix:  Foo` and you can pass your token using `Authorization: Foo eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9....9YR_D7N9E`

Answer (score 10):

The first solution works to solve "*401 - Bad authentication*" error.

But for **Apache** users that have the error "*401 - JWT Token not found*", the solution is to rewrite HTTP Authorization header of request, by placing following instructions on your virtualhost :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

You could find further readings about this issue on [documentation](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#important-note-for-apache-users), on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990388/request-headers-bag-is-missing-authorization-header-in-symfony-2) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443718/symfony-2-3-getrequest-headers-not-showing-authorization-bearer-token/19445020).

Comment: in my case, it was missing .htaccess in the /web directory. also, rewrite conditions could be added to .htaccess

Comment: I can confirm these apache settings. 
My error was similar. An InsufficientAuthenticationException was thrown. Our configuration was a VM with apache behind a nginx load balancer, reverse proxy and ssl termination vm. I'm pretty sure, that these lines weren't on our old servers without nginx gateway.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still having this problem especially after doing everything above, you can try something like this. Instead of using `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` you can use a custom http header such as `Php-Auth-Digest`. Using `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` can be tricky and could be removed from the request due to various different server settings (especially using shared server environments, cPanel and so on)

The config to accept custom http header in LexikJWT Bundle is  this,

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    # token extraction settings
    token_extractors:
         # look for a token as Authorization Header
        authorization_header:
            enabled: true
            prefix: Bearer
            name: Php-Auth-Digest
```

To find more about this visit this link - https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-configuration-reference.md

Sending the header from your api app would look like this (this is an example from Angular 6)

```
request = request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      "Php-Auth-Digest": `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`,
    }
  });
```

I hope this helps someone. Cheers.