# 401 error - JWT Token not found using fetch

Tags: apache, symfony, http, cors, fetch-api

I am new to react, and mostly to javascript.
I am using react for a web app hosted on localhost:3000 with node.js and symfony 2.8 for my back end, hosted on localhost:80 with apache, that exposes an api secured with lexik and fos user. 
Before securing the api, everything works fine.
After securing the api, I get a 401 error when using fetch as follow:

```
let myToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token') //token properly retrieved
let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", myToken)
return fetch(
    pathToMyResource,
    {
        method: "post",
        headers: myHeaders
    }
).then(do stuff with the answer)
```

This gives me the following error in the headers of the answer to the preflight request:

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1/edsa-food_app_symfony_2.8/api/site/1/get
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

And the response:

```
{"code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"}
```

I also checked, just because I don't really understand how this is supposed to work, with

```
credentials: 'include'
```

And

```
mode: 'no-cors'
```

But wasn't more successful.

When I build and send this same request using php from localhost:8000, it works perfectly. I use the following code:

```
$url = pathToMyResource
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer $token"
        'method'  => 'POST',
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

If I understand well it cannot be the apache error described in [Lexik JWT Token not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266160/lexik-jwt-token-not-found): the default .htaccess at the root of any symfony 2.8 project includes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
```

I checked and mod_rewrite is enabled.

Below are the headers as reported in Chrome:

```
**General**
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1/edsa-food_app_symfony_2.8/api/site/1/get
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers**
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:44
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 08 Aug 2017 01:05:20 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) PHP/5.6.19
WWW-Authenticate:Bearer
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.19

**Request Headers**
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4,zh-CN;q=0.2,zh;q=0.2,it;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:127.0.0.1
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
```

And for the POST request itself:

```
**General**
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1/edsa-food_app_symfony_2.8/api/site/1/get
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Request Headers**
Provisional headers are shown
authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhbnRvaW5lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTAyMTM4ODUwLCJleHAiOjE1MDIyMjUyNTB9.wpWZZLf5wWjrU0-eAQUR0XiDTvf1jRtiJuGIHoYm7Yo4lGhOn-_bYuJIdv71ZUiuYfaaMxOW4xzXN3JjB9KfrWmXD4jqI6CnHFYZISGlYvAGJayD_z8CMIEdvrMXrbb6_nEc0CaB68BOf7wqJyoNatFKlepwmCHevsRtTIbhc_GviQf_U_Fw30ShtogIJBLqmVD4ex-j0_9QbblAIqNhc8c0thEFYtN7FVepLehCzBNCTNL8l-mxYEFTrUYLKwSt4lRahgTsv4Ozhxl300xz7BbdQEr3ph2i4ssVcvokpEO2C07QicWSwXFx1Vx-2a6XbkoeorTz_P7WstBzinMdv0etlIz2VYN_oUmHaxDu9jlsu90nZlL2Ea7Ak7dSJaNYzmB11yga_OSiWMpzWTjaqP3MLJuS1O5keHMbliERgnBJM_rsMZ-mkVSM8j4t31L1QJCfP0RW-Vfj3biYR1uYNfXwbbdqmIpn6b39qOCY9l4F99dK6R-PKq5ZeBHEfy-OpN39NFmaMQQX5gYCQ3TzVdeou6-hjpqRnNl8dc0HYzAl3fbU102JMefZNvCsIdcI6WDCiyWZO9Viy-z9REAVF4Pr9bLFpc-Q6Lqdj32lt1-yy6i75IOavrPqRilhRh2z_V7rP_DqahrLhFSDPPVg_gcqb8n31_6q3wtyzx16aJ4
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/restaurant
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
```

I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your backend so that it responds to the preflight with a 200 or 204.

You may be able to handle that at the Apache level by adding your your Apache config this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

But if that doesn’t fix is then you gonna need to dig further and figure out what part of your backend system is causing authentication to be required for `OPTIONS` requests.

The reason is because what’s happening here is this:

1. Your code tells your browser it wants to send a request with the `Authorization` header.
2. Your browser says, OK, requests with the `Authorization` header require me to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` to make sure the server allows requests with that header.
3. Your browser sends the `OPTIONS` request to the server **without the `Authorization` header**—because the whole purpose of the `OPTIONS` check is to see if it’s OK to send that.
4. The server sees the `OPTIONS` request but instead of responding to it in a way that indicates it allows `Authorization` in requests, it rejects it with a 401 since it lacks that header.
5. Your browser expects a 200 or 204 response for the CORS preflight but instead gets that 401 response. So your browser stops right there and never tries the `POST` request from your code.

Comment: Ok thanks, it makes sense now. I tried your solution but it didn't solve the issue. Now that I understand where the problem comes from I think NelmioCorsBundle fro Symfony would solve the issue. I will look into it when I have time, but for now I am just going to pass my token via GET.