# How to fix: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, docker, cors

I am trying to build a simple API with a php backend and a React JS frontend. I am using two separate docker containers for this (api.dev.de and react.dev.de, as it is a requirement. I am using a slightly adapted version of the nginx proxy. However, when I send the request per React fetch() to the server, I get the error:

> Access to fetch at 'https: //api.dev.de/index.php?read=users' from 
>     origin 'https: //react.dev.de' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
>     Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
>     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
>     resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's 
>     mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Below you can see my request that I am trying to make and the .htaccess file.

I already looked up some solutions that worked for others, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin#answer-20453033)
one that I also wrote into my Dockerfile (and first enabling the extension for this image in my docker-compose.yml).

Furthermore I dug through 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work#answer-10636765)
answer and navigated through those links to other articles to build up some knowledge, but still no success...

Here are my code snippets.

Persons.js:

```
...

fetch('https://api.dev.de/index.php?read=users', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("<secretName>:<secretPass>"),
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    })

...
```

.htaccess:

```
Authtype Basic
AuthName "Protected section. Only for developers."
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/App/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

The config in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM thecodingmachine/php:7.3-v2-apache

...

RUN a2enmod headers

...
```

When executing the function, I get those console logs:

> Access to fetch at 'https:// api.dev.de/index.php?read=users' from 
>       origin 'https:// react.dev.de' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
>       Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
>       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
>       resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the 
>       request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS 
>       disabled.
>
> VM2133:1 POST https://api.dev.de/index.php?read=users 
>       net::ERR_FAILED

However, when I delete all authentication config in the .htaccess file as well deleting the `Authorization` and `Content-Type` section from the Persons.js file, I get a valid response. But I can't just exclude my authorization from the page.

When I build the React App and paste it in the same docker container as the API and then call it, everything is working fine. So I assume it is the config of the docker container (correct me if I am wrong).

## Update:

Since yesterday I tried out different things and came up with one last problem.

My fetch() function now looks like the following:

```
fetch('https://api.dev.de/index.php?read=users&pass=<password>', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    })
```

I also changed my .htaccess file:

```
# Enabled in the Dockerfile but still checking if it is enabled.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Content-Type "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Accept "*"
    # This should enable the authentication header
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
</IfModule>
```

Now the request works, but when I change the fetch() function to send an authorization header (`'Authorization': 'Basic: ' + btoa('<username>:<password>')`) and the .htaccess to this:

```
Authtype Basic
AuthName "Protected section. Only for developers."
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/App/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Content-Type "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Accept "*"
    # This should enable the authentication header
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
</IfModule>
```

I still get the error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.dev.de/index.php?read=users&pass=crud_restAPI_call' from origin 'https://react.dev.de' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

<s>Is this because the order of my .htaccess or do I need to modify something else?</s>

## Update 2:

As of my research, I found this answer to a similar issue: "The preflight request (OPTIONS), which is where i encounter the 401 unauthorized. I think this is because I've read that OPTIONS strips out some headers, including the Authentication header, so without that, it can't authenticate".

Source: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2076

Checking the developer.mozilla.org guide (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) I wanted to send the credentials always (to get the preflight request to succeed).

However, this does not work...

Has somebody an idea why it doesn't?

Updated fetch() function:

```
fetch('https://api.dev.de/index.php?read=users&pass=<password>', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic: ' + btoa('<secretName>:<secretPass>'),
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    })
```

I still get the same error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.dev.de/index.php?read=users&pass=crud_restAPI_call' from origin 'https://react.dev.de' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: In your apache config, you need to add handling for OPTIONS requests. See the answer and explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45559433/441757

Comment: @sideshowbarker I tried that out but nothing changed regarding the output. (sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preflight requests are not Docker related issue, they are browser-related policy. You're using HTTP headers that trigger the preflight mechanism, "Authorization" header in your case, and doing a cross-origin calls from the domain of your website to the `api.dev.de` domain.

You can [read this article](https://medium.com/@praveen.beatle/avoiding-pre-flight-options-calls-on-cors-requests-baba9692c21a) about avoiding preflights.

I would go with just adding an endpoint to your api server that responds to all `OPTIONS` requests with the appropriate CORS related headers (.e.g, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`)

Comment: Alright, I will try that out tomorrow and update this post then. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Okay, with your explanation I kinda knew what to do, now the basic auth is screwing me over.