# Authorization Header gets stripped on Symfony

Tags: php, android, symfony, react-native

Anyone who has an idea as to why Authorization headers gets stripped/dropped when getting headers from `Symfony->$request->headers->all()`, but `PHP->getAllHeaders()`is working properly and shows the authorization header as expected.

I'm trying to find another fix aside from doing the ff.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

The above snippet, was tried and is working.

Confused since, this is working on Web/Android/iOS/iOS-React-Native clients but not in Android-React-Native

Also Read few articles:

[Symfony 2.3 getRequest()->headers not showing Authorization Bearer Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443718/symfony-2-3-getrequest-headers-not-showing-authorization-bearer-token)